# Wha sholud i do? Ask

Tags: boot, networking, dual-boot, grub2

[image]

How do I fix this boot error in sda5 in Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please do not post pictures of error messages.  Browsers for the blind cannot render them

Comment: @Chenmunka There is no way to copy-paste that message from that screen. While we encourage users to post error messages as text from functional Ubuntu systems, that is simply not possible in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Run `fsck -y /dev/sda5`. Afterwards, run the command `exit` to reboot.

---

The problem occurred because the computer was not properly shut down. Maybe it ran out of battery, or you had to shut it down for some reason, or something else.

Answer (score -1):

You can try repairing your system in the recovery mode for Ubuntu.

To go to the recovery menu select `Advanced Options for Ubuntu` in the boot loader.

Then select the `recovery mode` option in the next screen, This should open the recovery options.

Select and run the option that says: `fsck Check all file systems` 

You can also try repairing any broken packages using the `dpkg` option in the same menu.